# Mx Cloner with Zenbu - only SuperAdmins can clone

Tags: zenbu, mx-cloner

I've had the mx cloner and zenbu add on working for a while now.  However, I set up some additional content groups, for others to make edits.

When I try "Cloning" an entry from another group, it looks like it's going to clone, but when you save it, it's actually just replacing the entry you had there.

I tried all the permissions I could find, but can't get this to work for any group but "Super Admins"

Any ideas?

-Jim

Comment: what version you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably that MX Cloner Accessory is activated for SuperAdmins only. It is why your entry is not cloned. Check if its assigned to another member groups.